# Is there an efficient arithmetic shortcuts that I can use to optimize the filtering of point clouds?

Tags: c#, optimization

I have a master point cloud, which essentially just a list of points with `{x,y}` coordinates.

The point cloud is HUGE ( like, it can contain more than 1 million points). The problem now is that I have another (sub)set of point clouds, and I need to check whether the points inside the second point clouds are the same with any of the points in the first point clouds, and then remove them from the list.

The characteristics of the second point cloud:

1. The second point cloud points are usually clustered in a corner of the first point cloud ( but not always).
2. None of the points from the second point cloud will lie outside of the first point cloud ( the first point cloud always contain every single point of the second point cloud)

The naive algorithm will be something like this:

```
public static List<Point> FilterPoints(Lis<Point> master, List<Point> subset)
   {    
    var FilteredPoints = new List<Point>();    
    for(int i=0; i< subset.Count; i++) 
    {
        var isContained = false;
        for(int j=0; j< master.Count; j++)
        {
          if(subset[i].X==master[j].X && subject[i].Y==master[j].Y)
          {
              isContained = true;
              break;
          }
        }
        if(!isContained)
        {
           FilteredPoints.Add( master[i]);
        }   
      } 
     return FilteredPoints; 
}
```

I'm using C#, the above version is the most readable ( but not necessarily most efficient) way of doing the job. Is there anyway to rewrite the above code-- while maintaining the same algorithm-- ( maybe to make use of the hidden C# optimization tricks or whatever) so that it can run faster than the above version?

PS: If there is a better algorithm to work with my particular scenario, I'm interested to hear it out too ( I've asked [the same thing](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/114877/304) at CS stack exchange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Point` class implements `Equals` or better yet `IEquatable<Point>`, you can get rid of the inner loop:

```
var isContained = subset.Contains(master[i]);
```

using `Linq` this can be further simplified:

```
public static List<Point> FilterPoints(List<Point> master, List<Point> subset)
{    
    return master.Where(p => !subset.Contains(p)).ToList();    
}
```

See also [List.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8)

(If the `Point` class does not implement `Equals` and you cannot change it, you can define your own `IEqualityComparer<Point>` class.)

For better efficiency, you might consider using `HashSet<Point>` for subset so the Contains method is in the best case (good Hash function) `O(1)` instead of `O(N)`:

```
public static List<Point> FilterPoints(List<Point> master, List<Point> subset)
{
    var subsetAsHashSet = new HashSet<Point>();
    return master.Where(p => !subsetAsHashSet.Contains(p)).ToList();    
}
```

I just had a look at the [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) of `Enumerable.Except` and this is exacly what this method does. So my final (both readable and efficient) answer would be:

```
public static List<Point> FilterPoints(List<Point> master, List<Point> subset)
{    
    return master.Except(subset).ToList();  
}
```